# I got this error while trying to install Node.Js

Tags: node.js

i got this error while trying to install Node.Js, can anyone help me?

Image link => https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooXbs.png

Comment: Do not link to images on StackOverflow. Attach them directly, or even better, include the error message. Tried hitting retry?

Answer (score 0):

@RemyK

There are some possible error solutions:

1. Not enough permissions | Run the downloader as administrator.
2. No Internet | Check your Internet.
3. Windows Defender thinks it can be dangerous | Desactivate Windows Firewall and try again.
4. Downloaded the wrong installer | Go to the Conntrol Panel, System and check of how many bits is your computer

Didn't help you these things? Contact node.js support: security@nodejs.org

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your reply, but unfortunately, none of the solutions listed above match, I had already tried them, I just tested everything again, I really don't know what this error could be due to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I did not find the problem. But i tried an older version and it worker without a problem.
I had the issue with the 14.17.2 (LTS Version) and 16.4.1 version. But the v14.15.4 worked for me.
Here you can see the previous releases of nodeJs: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/